# I am writing a program for a class that involves inputting and keeping track of totals and sub totals for each individual person in a restaurant

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
package restaurantMenu;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RestaurantMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] itemName = { " ", "Soup", "Wings", "Burger", "Chicken Sandwich", "Fries", "Pie", "Ice Cream",
                "Soft Drink", "Coffee" };
        double[] itemPrice = { 0, 2.50, .15, 4.95, 5.95, 1.99, 2.95, 2.99, 1.50, 1.00 };

        double grandTotal = 0;
        double total = 0;

        System.out.println("How many people in the party? ");
        int partyNumber = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < partyNumber; i++) {
            System.out.println("Discount type:");
            System.out.println("--------------");
            System.out.println("1: Child");
            System.out.println("2. Teen");
            System.out.println("3: Senior");
            System.out.println("4. None of the above");
            int discount = input.nextInt();

            for (int k = 0; k < itemName.length; k++) {
                System.out.println(itemName[k] + "   ");
            }

            for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {

                System.out.println("Please select menu item: ");
                int itemNum = input.nextInt();

                if (itemNum == 2) {
                    System.out.println("How many do you want? ");
                    int amount = input.nextInt();
                    itemPrice[2] = itemPrice[2] * amount;
                }

                total = total + itemPrice[itemNum];

            }

            System.out.println(total);

            if (discount == 1)
                total = total * 0;
            else if (discount == 2 || discount == 3)
                total = total * .75;
            else
                total = total + (total * .05);

            grandTotal = total;

        }
        System.out.println(grandTotal);
    }
}
```

So, what I'm thinking is the total is not resetting upon jumping out of the second for loop, but I don't necessarily know if I need it to. What I'm wondering is why can't I get the total to track properly, output the `grandTotal`, and discount everything properly for multiple people. If anyone needs the input data that was provided to me from the teacher let me know.

Comment: Hint: start by using { braces } for your if/else blocks. That helps with *reading* a lot. And yes, a "full" example with input and expected+actual output would definitely help.

Comment: You may also want to think about taking the time to learn how classes and inheritance work. i.e., You can have a `Item` class, that has a `name` and `price`. and many other combinations.

Comment: Then: you have **one** check ` if (itemNum == 2) {` ... but what if the item number is anything else?! Long story short, this code is kinda really confusing. You have arrays that list product names and prices, but you **not** using them at allow. You should **not** expect that we magically figure what your homework should look like to then hold hands and explaining all the steps for it to you!

Comment: @GhostCat Presumably only the "Wings" allow you to specify an amount. But there seems to be a fatal flaw in that ordering (for example) three wings will triple the price of all future wings...

Comment: Thank you all very much. I will keep all of this in mind or future projects.

Comment: Sorry for the mess of the post. This is a very basic, not meant to be implemented program to test us on the use of arrays. We weren't suppose to create different methods for this program. We were supposed to do the whole thing in the main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the englobing for loop, reset total, and grandTotal must add total.

`grandTotal += total;
total = 0;`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you very much.